# Jsoup Maven installation- Angular

Tags: angular, maven, jsoup

I'm having an issue with Jsoup installation. I'm using Maven in intelliJ IDE. I have installed the pom dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, I'm getting the following error:
Cannot find name 'Jsoup' when I run the below code:

```
public doc: Document = Jsoup.connect("http://example.com/").get();
```

I've also imported the below:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Try running a maven build to see if pom is up to date?

Comment: Still getting the same error after rebuilding...

Comment: check and make sure your intelliJ can see external libs has jsoup

Comment: Checked for that within the Project Structure, it seems to have Jsoup in the external libs.

Comment: not sure then I'm guessing it's your import

Comment: It is a Java library and I'm trying to use it with Typescript...I didn't know it was a Java library and could only be used with Java language. Thank you for your help, anyway.